# Using Moq to mock an asynchronous method for a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I am testing a method for a service that makes a Web `API` call. Using a normal `HttpClient` works fine for unit tests if I also run the web service (located in another project in the solution) locally.

However when I check in my changes the build server won't have access to the web service so the tests will fail.

I've devised a way around this for my unit tests by creating an `IHttpClient` interface and implementing a version that I use in my application. For unit tests, I make a mocked version complete with a mocked asynchronous post method. Here's where I have run into problems. I want to return an OK `HttpStatusResult` for this particular test. For another similar test I will be returning a bad result.

The test will run but will never complete. It hangs at the await. I am new to asynchronous programming, delegates, and Moq itself and I've been searching SO and google for a while learning new things but I still can't seem to get past this problem.

Here is the method I am trying to test:

```
public async Task<bool> QueueNotificationAsync(IHttpClient client, Email email)
{
    // do stuff
    try
    {
        // The test hangs here, never returning
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

        // more logic here
    }
    // more stuff
}
```

Here's my unit test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task QueueNotificationAsync_Completes_With_ValidEmail()
{
    Email email = new Email()
    {
        FromAddress = "bob@example.com",
        ToAddress = "bill@example.com",
        CCAddress = "brian@example.com",
        BCCAddress = "ben@example.com",
        Subject = "Hello",
        Body = "Hello World."
    };
    var mockClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
    mockClient.Setup(c => c.PostAsync(
        It.IsAny<Uri>(),
        It.IsAny<HttpContent>()
        )).Returns(() => new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(() => new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)));

    bool result = await _notificationRequestService.QueueNotificationAsync(mockClient.Object, email);

    Assert.IsTrue(result, "Queue failed.");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

You're creating a task but never starting it, so it's never completing. However, don't just start the task - instead, change to using [`Task.FromResult<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will give you a task which has already completed:

```
...
.Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)));
```

Note that you won't be testing the actual asynchrony this way - if you want to do that, you need to do a bit more work to create a `Task<T>` that you can control in a more fine-grained manner... but that's something for another day.

You might also want to consider using a fake for `IHttpClient` rather than mocking everything - it really depends on how often you need it.

Comment: Re: Fake IHttpClient, I considered that but I needed to be able to return different HttpStatusCodes for different tests based on the expected behavior coming back from the web API, and this seemed to give me more control.

Comment: @mvanella: Yes, so you'd create a fake which can return whatever you want it to. Just something to think about.

Comment: @sgrassie Can you provide a link to some documentation? I can't find any reference to it in the API docs. [link](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/Moq)

Comment: @legacybass I can't find a link to any documentation for it, even though the API docs says they're built against v4.2.1312.1622 which was [released](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.2.1312.1622) almost exactly a year ago. See [this commit](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/commits/master/Source/ReturnsExtensions.cs) which was made a few days before that release. As to why the API documents aren't update...

Comment: @sgrassie Thanks! Weirdly, my DLL from NuGet still shows it under the Moq namespace. Moq is version 4.2.1409.1722. I guess it hasn't moved to the stable release yet. Still, good to know.

Comment: Note: this solution makes synchronous version of asynchronous operation. This may cause code that incorrectly uses async operations (i.e. missing `await`) to pass tests.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yup, hence "Note that you won't be testing the actual asynchrony this way". For more, we'd need to know what aspects were being tested.

Comment: Starting with Moq 4.16 you can no longer use the `ReturnsAsync` method. See the [documentation](https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#async-methods) for more info.

Comment: Docs recommend setting up on the `Result` property, i.e. `.Setup(x => x.DoAsync().Result).Returns(...)`. Wondering if there's any hidden pitfalls to either approach.

Answer (score 77):

Recommend @Stuart Grassie's comment. Use Moq's `ReturnsAsync`.

```
var moqCredentialMananger = new Mock<ICredentialManager>();
moqCredentialMananger
                    .Setup(x => x.GetCredentialsAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .ReturnsAsync(new Credentials() { .. .. .. });
```

Comment: No longer supported: https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#async-methods

Answer (score 8):

Try using `ReturnsAsync`.
In asynchronous methods it works, I believe the basis to solve your problem should be similar.

```
_mocker.GetMock<IMyRepository>()
     .Setup(x => x.GetAll())
     .ReturnsAsync(_myFakeListRepository.GetAll());
```

Answer (score 7):

With `Mock.Of<...>(...)` for `async` method you can use `Task.FromResult(...)`:

```
var client = Mock.Of<IHttpClient>(c => 
    c.PostAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<HttpContent>()) == Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
);
```