# How do I set up a verifiable expectation on a mocked async method?

Tags: async-await, moq, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to use Moq to test integration between a WebAPI controller and a Redis database, using the StackExchange.Redis client, and cannot work out how to set up a verifiable expectation on a mocked async method that includes a callback or some other assertion behaviour.

Ordinarily, I'd use the following syntax:

```
const string KEY = "some_key";
var db = new Mock<IDatabase>();
db.Setup(d => d.HashSetAsync(KEY, It.IsAny<HashEntry[]>(),It.IsAny<CommandFlags>()))
    .Callback<RedisKey,HashEntry[],CommandFlags>((key, hash, flags) => {
                hash.ShouldContain(entry => entry.Name == "customerid");
                hash.ShouldContain(entry => entry.Name == "quotenumber");
     })
     .Verifiable();
```

But this is giving me:

> 'Moq.Language.Flow.IReturnsThrows<StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not contain a definition for 'Verifiable' and no extension method 'Verifiable' accepting a first argument of type 'Moq.Language.Flow.IReturnsThrows' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I change `db.HashSetAsync` to `db.HashSet` in the `Setup` invocation, it works as expected. It appears that the setting a Callback on a regular method returns an `ICallbackResult` but setting a callback on an async method invocation returns an `IReturnsThrows` - and I'm not sure how you mark one of those as verifiable. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be missing a return from your setup for the call back. what type does `HashSetAsync` return

Comment: Why don't you use `ReturnsAsync`? In versions that don't have it you can use `.Returns(Task.FromResult(someValue));`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so far I haven't come across `ReturnsAsync`. Where do I look for that? looks interesting.

Comment: What Moq version are you using? It's available in Moq 4.2. Even before this, you can return a filled Task with `Task.FromResult`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using v4.2.1510.2205

Comment: Check the duplicate question. The *second* answer says that `RetunrsAsync` is available only for methods that return `Task<T>`. You can still use `.Returns(Task.FromResult(...));`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes now I see. learned something new today. thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For async methods you need to return a completed `Task` from the setup before using a callback

have a look here:

[Using Moq to mock an asynchronous method for a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859715/5233410)

> You're creating a task but never starting it, so it's never
>   completing. However, don't just start the task - instead, change to
>   using [`Task.FromResult<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will give you a task which has
>   already completed:

this works

```
const string KEY = "some_key";
var db = new Mock<IDatabase>();
db.Setup(d => d.HashSetAsync(KEY, It.IsAny<HashEntry[]>(), It.IsAny<CommandFlags>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<object>(null))
    .Callback<RedisKey, HashEntry[], CommandFlags>((key, hash, flags) => {
        hash.ShouldContain(entry => entry.Name == "customerid");
        hash.ShouldContain(entry => entry.Name == "quotenumber");
    })
    .Verifiable();
```