# Setting up a C# Test with Moq against Async methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, moq

I'm trying to create a set of test methods using Moq to cover the external dependencies.  These dependencies are async in nature and I have come across a set of them that when awaited they never return, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

The test itself is very simple.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateItemAsync()
{
    var repository = GetRepository();
    var result = await repository.UpdateItemAsync("", new object());
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

The `GetRepository` method above is what sets up the various mock objects including called Setup on them.

```
private static DocumentDbRepository<object> GetRepository()
{
    var client = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

    client.Setup(m => m.ReplaceDocumentAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<RequestOptions>()))
        .Returns(() =>
        {
            return new Task<ResourceResponse<Document>>(() => new ResourceResponse<Document>());
        });

    var repository = new DocumentDbRepository<object>(configuration, client.Object);
    return repository;
}
```

The code that is under test is listed below and when the line with the await is executed it never returns.

```
public async Task<T> UpdateItemAsync(string id, T item)
{
    var result = await Client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id), item);
    return result.Resource as T;
}
```

I'm sure that the error is in the `Setup` method on the Moq object in the `GetRepository` method, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Moq to mock an asynchronous method for a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859639/using-moq-to-mock-an-asynchronous-method-for-a-unit-test)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to fix the set up on the async calls

Moq has a `ReturnsAsync` that would allow the mocked async method calls to flow to completion.

```
client
    .Setup(_ => _.ReplaceDocumentAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<RequestOptions>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new ResourceResponse<Document>());
```

You typically want to avoid newing up `Task`s manually

Comment: Thank You.  I don't know why I didn't see that.